After git lfs migration, "refusing to merge unrelated histories" happens when pull
I applied git LFS to my repository. The commands I used were:
( There are no branches in this repository. )
git lfs migrate import --include="*.uasset"
git push --force origin master

There were no errors.
But today, the other one told me the error below popped up when he tried to pull from the repository that I applied the git lfs:
( He also has no branches. )
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

I googled and in many cases, the solution was execute the command below:
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories

or
git push --force origin master

When I applied the git lfs, I already push new local history forcefully to the remote so I think the first answer(=allowing unrelated histories) is what I have to tell him.
Am I getting this right?
Thank you.

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2991 , https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4187 , https://www.google.com/search?q=%22git+lfs%22+%22refusing+to+merge+unrelated+histories%22

@phd, Hello, I also checked the answer you mentioned and found above two commands. But couldn't find the answer that can be applied to my case...

Both command I asked above didn't work.
But the command below solved the issue:
git lfs install
git reset --hard origin/master

I migrated my local repo to LFS and pushed new history to remote. So what the other one who uses the repository has to do is installing lfs(it adds hook to git pull command) and reset his local history to origin's.

Be aware that git reset --hard origin/master may erase local work. Use the command with care and only when you know what you are doing. (Just following instructions given by random websites does not count as "knowing what one is doing".)

I agree with you. Don't forget to commit or stash before run "git reset". Thank you. :D
